# Determine size of a BLOB column

Tags: c#, arrays, resize

Am pulling a BLOB from a data base and storing in a Byte array.  Initially it is defined as same size as BLOB colum on DB, which is quite large.

```
int maxsize = 20971520;
int thisSize;
Byte[] picture = new Byte[maxsize];
```

so I grab the blob:

```
rdr.GetBytes(3, 0, picture, 0, maxsize);
```

and then write it to disk:

```
FileStream fstream = new FileStream(ImageFullName,FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.Write);
BinaryWriter bwriter = new BinaryWriter(fstream);
bwriter.Write(picture);
bwriter.Flush();
bwriter.Close();
fstream.Close();
```

The problem is that most of these blobs are considerably smaller that that maxsize, so how do I resize the Byte array to the actual size of the blob column?

Answer (score 2):

Why not query to see the length of the field so the byte[] is the correct size the first time.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbytes.aspx)

> If you pass a buffer that is null,
>   GetBytes returns the length of the
>   entire field in bytes, not the
>   remaining size based on the buffer
>   offset parameter.

So your code would become

```
long length = rdr.GetBytes(3, 0, null, 0, maxsize);

Byte[] picture = new Byte[length];

rdr.GetBytes(3, 0, picture, 0, length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.Resize<T>(ref T[] array, int newSize)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx)